# how to find latitude and longitude every second without using GPS

Tags: android, google-maps, locationmanager, google-location-services

i want to find latitude and longitude of user current position and insert in db  every second. and drawer a path according to all  latitude and longitude of user move on location without using GPS

Comment: without GPS you cannot get user exact location. if you not want to turn on GPS then use Network Provider for get user location but its not user accurate location.

Comment: If you do not want to use gps then what do you want to use?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use GPS you can use services which use WLAN, Bluetooth or CellTower information to determine the position of a device. For Example the [Mozilla Location Service](https://location.services.mozilla.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Only way how you can do it is position based on mobile signal strength https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html but this methode is not very accurate. 
Don´t forget on permission in manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Then just register a listener and get the updates

```
LocationManager manager = (LocationManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

manager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1, 10, listener);
```

Comment: i already  try to using network provider and  location service but find  wrong latitude and longitude

Comment: This metode is not very accurate but is it only way how to locate device without GPS